# Generic update of "normal" columns with data from JSON

Tags: postgresql, update, json

I am trying to do a "generic" insert/update of table columns using JSON. There are tons of info how to update a JSON *column*, but I have found none that updates several normal columns in a table generic.

**Insert columns with JSON data works**

This works as I understand it in a generic way:

```
INSERT INTO inputtable
SELECT *
FROM json_populate_record (NULL::inputtable,
    '{
      "id": "0",
      "name": "orkb type foo examples tutorials orkb",
      "sum": 5743,
      "float_col": 94.55681687716474
    }'
);
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaQG8H4yqY9hnQBZjzJgz/29

**Update columns with JSON data?**

There are examples of "non-generic" update using JSON, but I am searching for a "generic" solution. In my dreams it should work as this pseudo code:

```
with data as (
select * from json_each_text(
    '{
      "id": "0",
      "name": "orkb type foo examples tutorials orkb",
      "sum": 5743,
      "float_col": 95
    }')
)
update inputtable set = (select * from data) where id=0
```

Is this possible to do? If it is, how do I do this?

**EDIT**

I have found no other way than [hardcode the update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274296/update-postgresql-table-straight-from-a-json-object)

```
update inputtable
set
    (id, name, sum, float_col) =
    (j.id, j.name, j.sum, j.float_col)
from jsonb_populate_record ( null::inputtable,
      '{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "test",
      "sum": 5432,
      "float_col": 94.1
    }'::jsonb
) j;

select * from inputtable;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaQG8H4yqY9hnQBZjzJgz/36

Though I found that PostgREST may doing it another way. They claim that they not are an ORM magic. But how do they do this?

```
PATCH /table_name?myPKey=eq.thePKey
{ "col1":"update-value1", "col2":"update-value2" }
```

Comment: You could write a routine using dynamic sql based on the results of json_each_text.  Only go there if you have enough CPU power to spare.

Comment: You mean a function? Any tip or link that gives a clue?

Comment: "dynamic sql" was meant to be the tip.  To be used perhaps in a pre-insert trigger, or instead-of-insert trigger if Postgresql knows these.

Comment: You have to specify the individual columns in the `SET` clause, there is no way around that.

Comment: So the answer is NO. This cannot be done generic?

Comment: PostgREST have in their documentation 
PATCH /table_name?myPKey=eq.thePKey
{ "col1":"update-value1", "col2":"update-value2" }
Do they ”convert” this in PostgREST?

Comment: @sibert I am pretty sure PostgREST will (dynamically) generate an UPDATE statement that lists each column in the SET clause.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  "will (dynamically) generate an UPDATE statement that lists each column in the SET clause" Can this be done in a function in Postgresql? Without using PostgREST?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN